# покритикуйте пожалуйста мой код, игра pin pong

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, pygame

Дайте советы, как можно было бы сделать лучше сие творение, и что можно было бы добавить. Я только начал разбираться в библиотеке pygame, но буду рад любой мелочи. Так же в коде вылезает ошибка, и я не знаю как её исправить, а так он вроде как работает. В общем меня интересует: решение и причина ошибки  `pygame.error: video system not initialized` и критика моего кода.

КОД самой игры:

```
import pygame as pg
from random import choice
from math import fabs
from class_pong import *
pg.font.init()

# ЭКРАН И РАБОТА ЦИКЛА
HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 1000
FPS = 60

# СОЗДАНИЕ ЭКРАНА
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# КНОПКИ 1 И 2 ИГРОКА
One_player = False
Two_player = False

# СТАРТ ДЛЯ ИГРОВОГО ЦИКЛА
going = True
# СТАРТ ДЛЯ МЕНЮ
start = True


def Menu_start():
    '''СОЗДАЁТ НА ЭКРАНЕ 2 КНОПКИ В ПОСЛЕДСТВИИ
                ПЕРЕХОДЯ К ИГРЕ'''

    global One_player, Two_player, going, start

    # СОЗДАНИЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ КЛАССА MENU
    One_player_button = Menu()
    Two_player_button = Menu()

    # СЁТЧИК ДЛЯ ВЫПОНЕНИЯ ПРОГРАММЫ 1 РАЗ
    counter_circle = 0

    # ЦИКЛ МКНЮ
    while start:

        # ИГРОВОЕ ПОЛЕ
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        pg.draw.line(screen, WITHE, 
            [WIDTH // 2, 0], 
            [WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT], 5)
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (500, 300), 10)


        # СОБЫТИЯ
        for i in pg.event.get():
            if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                going = False
                start = False
                pg.quit()

        # СОЗДАЁТ 2 КНОПКИ
        One_player_button.Make_button('1 ИГРОК', 425, 400)  # КНОПКА 1 ИГРА С БОТОМ
        Two_player_button.Make_button('2 ИГРОКA', 425, 500) # КНОПКА ДЛЯ ИГРЫ ВДВОЁМ

        # НАЖАТИЕ НА 1 КНОПКУ
        if One_player_button.pressed[0] and One_player_button.rect_text.collidepoint(One_player_button.pos) and counter_circle == 0:
            counter_circle = 1
            One_player = True
            start = False
            Game_start()

        # НАЖАТИЕ НА 2 КНОПКУ
        if Two_player_button.pressed[0] and Two_player_button.rect_text.collidepoint(Two_player_button.pos) and counter_circle == 0:
            counter_circle = 1
            Two_player = True
            start = False
            Game_start()

        # ОТРИСОВКА КНОПОК
        screen.blit(One_player_button.text, One_player_button.rect_text)
        screen.blit(Two_player_button.text, Two_player_button.rect_text)

        # ОБНОАЛЕНИЕ ЭКРАНА
        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)



def Game_start():
    '''ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ ЦИКЛ ИГРЫ "PIN PONG"
    ПРИ НАЖАТИИ НА КНОПКУ "MENU" ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ В МЕНЮ'''

    global screen, clock, FPS, WIDTH, HEIGHT, One_player, Two_player, start, going

    # ЦВЕТА
    WITHE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    # СКОРОСТЬ ОБЪЕКТОВ
    speed_boll = [2, -2]
    speed_boll_x = choice(speed_boll)
    speed_boll_y = choice(speed_boll)
    speed_palyer = 3
    speed_bot = speed_boll[0] - 1

    # КООРДИНАТА 'X' ДВУХ ИГРОКОВ
    player_x_one = 20
    player_x_two = 970

    # ОЧКИ ИГРОКОВ
    score_one = 0
    score_two = 0

    # КООРДИНАТЫ МЯЧА И РАДИУС
    x = WIDTH // 2
    y = HEIGHT // 2
    r = 10

    # СОЗДАНИЕ ИГРОКОВ
    first_player = Game(player_x_one, 225, 2, speed_palyer)
    second_player = Game(player_x_two, 225, 1, speed_palyer)
    bot = Game(player_x_two, 225, 3, speed_palyer)

    # ТЕКСТ
    score1 = pg.font.Font(None, 50)
    score2 = pg.font.Font(None, 50)
    speed_text = pg.font.Font(None, 50)

    # СЧЁТЧИК ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩИЙ СКОРОСТЬ
    counter = 0

    # СОЗДАНИЕ ОБЪЕКТА КЛАССА MENU
    pause = Menu()
    

    # ИГРОВОЙ ЦИКЛ
    while going:
        # СЩЗДАНИЕ КНОПКИ ДЛЯ ПЕРЕХОДА К МЕНЮ
        pause.Make_button('Menu', 950, 20, 15, 25, 50)

        # ИГРОВОЕ ПОЛЕ
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        pg.draw.line(screen, WITHE, 
            [WIDTH // 2, 0], 
            [WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT], 5)

        # ТЕКСТ
        text1 = score1.render(str(score_one), True, WITHE)
        text2 = score2.render(str(score_two), True, WITHE)
        text3 = speed_text.render('Speed: ' + str(fabs(speed_boll_x)), True, WITHE)

        # ИГРОВЫЕ СОБЫТИЯ
        for i in pg.event.get():
            if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                going = False
                start = False
                pg.quit()

        # МЯЧ
        boll = pg.draw.circle(screen, WITHE, (x, y), r)

        # ФИЗИКА МЯЧА
        x += speed_boll_x
        y += speed_boll_y

        # ПРИ СТОЛКНОВЕНИИ МЯЧА С ПРАВОЙ ГРАНИЦЕЙ:
        if x > WIDTH-r:

            # ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩЕГО СЧЁТЧИКА
            counter = 0

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ КООРДИНАТ МЯЧА
            x = WIDTH // 2 
            y = HEIGHT // 2 

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ ОТДАЧИ
            first_player.x = player_x_one

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ ОТДАЧИ У:
            if Two_player:
                second_player.x = player_x_two  # ВТОРОГО ИГРОКА
            elif One_player:
                bot.x = player_x_two # БОТА

            # ЗАЧИСЛЕНИЕ ОЧКОВ ПЕРВОМУ ИГРОКУ
            score_one += 1 

            # ОТЛЁТ МЯЧА В РАНДОМНОМ НАПРАВЛЕНИИ
            speed_boll_x = choice(speed_boll)   
            speed_boll_y = choice(speed_boll) 

            # ОБНУЛЕНИИ СКОРОСТИ ПЕРВОГО ИГРОКА
            first_player.speed = 2.5  

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У:
            if Two_player:
                second_player.speed = 2.5   # ВТОРОГО ИГРОКА
            elif One_player:
                bot.speed = abs(speed_boll_x) - 1   # БОТА


        # ПРИ СТОЛКНОВЕНИИ МЯЧА С ЛЕВОЙ ГРАНИЦЕЙ:
        elif x < r:

            # ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩЕГО СЧЁТЧИКА
            counter = 0 

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ КООРДИНАТ МЯЧА
            x = WIDTH // 2
            y = HEIGHT // 2

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ ОТДАЧИ
            first_player.x = player_x_one

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ ОТДАЧИ У:
            if Two_player:
                second_player.x = player_x_two  # ВТОРОГО ИГРОКА
            elif One_player:
                bot.x = player_x_two    # БОТА


            # ЗАЧИСЛЕНИЕ ОЧКОВ ВТОРОМУ ИГРОКУ И БОТУ
            score_two += 1

            # ОТЛЁТ МЯЧА В РАНДОМНОМ НАПРАВЛЕНИИ
            speed_boll_x = choice(speed_boll)
            speed_boll_y = choice(speed_boll)

            # ОБНУЛЕНИИ СКОРОСТИ ПЕРВОГО ИГРОКА
            first_player.speed = 2.5

            # ОБНУЛЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У:
            if Two_player:
                second_player.speed = 2.5   # ВТОРОГО ИГРОКА
            elif One_player:
                bot.speed = abs(speed_boll_x)   # БОТА


        # СТАЛКНОВЕНИЕ МЯЧА С ВЕРХНЕЙ И НИЖНЕЙ ГРАНИЦЕЙ
        elif y > HEIGHT-r or y < r:
            # ОТСКОК МЯЧКА
            speed_boll_y *= -1


        # ИГРОКИ
        first_player.Movements()    # ПЕРВЫЙ ИГРОК
        if Two_player:
            second_player.Movements()   #  ВТОРОЙ ИГРОК
        elif One_player:
            bot.Movements(abs(speed_boll_x), x, y, (500, 0, 500, 600))  # БОТ


        # ФИЗИА СТОЛКНОВЕНИЯ МЯЧА С ИГРОКОМ И ОТДАЧА В РАКЕТКУ
        roll = abs(speed_boll_y) * 2

        # СТОЛКНОВЕНИЕ С 1 ИГРОКОМ
        if first_player.rect.colliderect(boll):
            #  ОТДАЧА В РАКЕТКУ 1 ИГРОКА
            first_player.x -= roll
            # ОТСКО ОТ РАКЕТКИ
            speed_boll_x *= -1


            if counter < 16:
                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩЕГО СЧЁТЧИКА
                counter += 1

                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У:
                if Two_player:
                    second_player.speed += 0.5  # ВТОРОГО ИГРОКА
                elif One_player:
                    bot.speed += 0.5    # БОТА

                # ПОВЫШЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У МЯЧА ПРИ СТОЛКНОВЕНИИ С 1 ИГРОКОМ
                if speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5

            # ОТКАТ ОТДАЧИ у:
            if Two_player:
                if second_player.x > player_x_two:
                    second_player.x = player_x_two  # 2 ИГРОКА
            elif One_player:
                if bot.x > player_x_two:
                    bot.x = player_x_two    # БОТА

        # СТОЛКНОВЕНИЕ С 2 ИГРОКОМ
        elif Two_player and second_player.rect.colliderect(boll):

            # ОТДАЧА В РАКЕТКУ 2 ИГРОКА
            second_player.x += roll
            # ОТСКО ОТ РАКЕТКИ
            speed_boll_x *= -1
            
            
            if counter < 16:
                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ 2 ИГРОКА
                first_player.speed += 0.5
                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩЕГО СЧЁТЧИКА
                counter += 1

                # ПОВЫШЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У МЯЧА ПРИ СТОЛКНОВЕНИИ С 2 ИГРОКОМ 
                if speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5

            # ОТКАТ ОТДАЧИ У ПЕРВОГО ИГРОКА
            if first_player.x < player_x_one:
                first_player.x += player_x_one

        # СТОЛКНОВЕНИЕ С БОТОМ
        elif One_player and bot.rect.colliderect(boll):

            # ОТДАЧА В РАКЕТКУ  БОТА
            bot.x += roll
            # ОТСКО ОТ РАКЕТКИ
            speed_boll_x *= -1

            
            if counter < 16:
                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ БОТА
                first_player.speed += 0.5
                # УВЕЛИЧЕНИЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЮЩЕГО СЧЁТЧИКА
                counter += 1

                # ПОВЫШЕНИЕ СКОРОСТИ У МЯЧА ПРИ СТОЛКНОВЕНИИ С БОТОМ
                if speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
                    speed_boll_x += 0.5
                    speed_boll_y -= 0.5
                elif speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
                    speed_boll_x -= 0.5
                    speed_boll_y += 0.5

            # ОТКАТ ОТДАЧИ У ПЕРВОГО ИГРОКА
            if first_player.x < player_x_one:
                first_player.x += player_x_one


        # ПРИ НАЖАТИИ НА КНОПКУ 'MENU'
        if pause.pressed[0] and pause.rect_text.collidepoint(pause.pos):
            counter_circle = 0
            Two_player = False
            One_player = False
            start = True
            Menu_start() # ЗАПУСК ОКНА МЕНЮ

        # ПРОРИСОВКА ТЕКСТ
        screen.blit(text1, (460, 10))
        screen.blit(text2, (525, 10))
        screen.blit(text3, (300, 550))

        # ПРОРИСОВКА ПАУЗЫ
        screen.blit(pause.text, pause.rect_text)

        # ПРОРИСОВКА 1 ИГРОКА
        screen.blit(first_player.player, first_player.rect)  

        # ПРОРИСОВКА БОТА ИЛИ 2 ИГРОКА
        if Two_player:
            screen.blit(second_player.player, second_player.rect)   # 2 ИГРОКА
        elif One_player:
            screen.blit(bot.player, bot.rect)   # БОТА

        # ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ЭКРАНА И FPS
        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


# СЧЁТЧИК ЗАПУЧКА ИГРОВОГО МЕНЮ В НАЧАЛЕ
counter_game = 0

# ЗАПУСК ИГРЫ С ИГРОВОГО МЕНЮ
if counter_game == 0:
    counter_game = 1
    Menu_start()
```

Классы игры:

```
import pygame as pg

WITHE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
HEIGHT = 600


class Game:

    def __init__(self, x = None, y = None, Num_player = None, speed_palyer = None):
        self.num = Num_player
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed_palyer


    def Movements(self, speed_boll = None,x_boll = None, y_boll = None, visibility_parameters = None):
        '''СОЗДАЁТ ИГРОКА И ПРИСВАИВАЕТСЯ ОДНО 
    ИЗ ДВУХ УПРАЛЕНИЙ К НЕМУ ИЛИ ЖЕ СОЗДАЁТ БОТА'''
        self.y_boll = y_boll
        self.x_boll = x_boll
        self.speed_boll = speed_boll
        self.par_vis = visibility_parameters

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        # СОЗДАЁТ ИГРОКА
        self.player = pg.Surface((10, 150))
        self.player.fill(WITHE)
        self.rect = pg.Rect((self.x, self.y, 10, 150))

        # УПРАВЛЕНИЕ К СОЗДАННУМУ ИГРОКУ
        if self.num == 1:    # УПРАВЛЕНИЕ К 1 ИГРОКУ
            if keys[pg.K_UP] and self.y > 0:
                self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pg.K_DOWN] and self.y < HEIGHT - 150:
                self.y += self.speed

        elif self.num == 2:    # УПРАВЛЕНИЕ К 2 ИГРОКУ
            if keys[pg.K_w] and self.y > 0:
                self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pg.K_s] and self.y < HEIGHT - 150:
                self.y += self.speed

        elif self.num == 3:    # УПРАВЛЕНИЕ К БОТУ

            # СОЗДАНИЕ ПОЛЕ ВИДИМОСТИ БОТА
            self.rect_v = pg.Rect(self.par_vis)

            # ПРОВЕРЯЕТ НАХОДИТЬСЯ ЛИ МЯЧ В ПОЛЕ ВИДИМОСТИ
            if self.rect_v.collidepoint(self.x_boll, self.y_boll):

                # КОНТРОЛЬ СКОРОСТИ БОТА
                if self.y+75 < self.y_boll:
                    if speed_boll < 5:
                        self.y += self.speed_boll - 0.5
                    elif 5 < speed_boll < 10:
                        self.y += self.speed_boll - 1
                    else:
                        self.y += self.speed_boll - 1.5

                elif self.y+75 > self.y_boll:
                    if speed_boll < 5:
                        self.y -= self.speed_boll - 0.5
                    elif 5 < speed_boll < 10:
                        self.y -= self.speed_boll - 1
                    else:
                        self.y -= self.speed_boll - 1.5

                # ПРОВЕРЯЕТ НЕ УХОДИТ ЛИ РАКЕТКА ЗА ГРАНИЦУ
                if self.y < 0:
                    self.y = 1
                elif self.y > 450:
                    self.y = 449


class Menu:
    
    def Make_button(self, text, x_text, y_text, size = 40, width = 150, height = 50):
        '''СОЗДАЁТ КНОПКУ И ПОЛУЧАЕТ 
            КООРДИНАТУ КЛИКА МЫШИ'''

        self.text = text
        self.x_text = x_text
        self.y_text = y_text
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.size = size

        self.pressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        self.pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()

        self.button = pg.font.SysFont('arial', self.size)
        self.text = self.button.render(self.text, True, WITHE, (0, 0, 0))
        self.rect_text = pg.Rect((self.x_text, self.y_text, self.width, self.height))
```

Ошибка которая появляется после нескольких смен режимов игры:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 395, in <module>
    Menu_start()
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 66, in Menu_start
    Game_start()
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 365, in Game_start
    Menu_start() # ЗАПУСК ОКНА МЕНЮ
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 73, in Menu_start
    Game_start()
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 365, in Game_start
    Menu_start() # ЗАПУСК ОКНА МЕНЮ
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\pong_game.py", line 58, in Menu_start
    One_player_button.Make_button('1 ИГРОК', 425, 400)  # КНОПКА 1 ИГРА С БОТОМ
  File "E:\Python_game\pong_game\class_pong.py", line 90, in Make_button
    self.pressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добавьте перед `screen = ...` `pygame.init()`

Comment: **Код написан грамотно, придраться не к чему. Вы хороший программист!**

Comment: Нашёл строки в которых больше 79 символов, но это единичные случаи. Я считаю ваш код хорошим! Продолжайте в том же духе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понимаю, что критика не всегда воспринимается просто, но готовность к ее восприятию уже достойно уважения.

Критиковать чужой код можно до бесконечности, но я преследую цель лишь подсказать путь к рефакторингу.

Когда-то писал довольно сложную вещь на pygame - оконный менеджер.
И занимаясь оптимизацией по скорости и памяти выяснил что чем меньше глобальных переменных тем лучше (я сам был этому удивлен)

1. Поэтому все константы я занес бы в переменную конфига, переменные разместил в классе игры
2. Этот каунтер `counter_circle = 0 # СЁТЧИК ДЛЯ ВЫПОНЕНИЯ ПРОГРАММЫ 1 РАЗ`  и дальнейшее его использование в условиях говорит о не продуманной   архитектуре, в общем случае
   в нем нет никакой необходимости, данный вопрос можно решить иначе.
3. В `Menu_start` полно дублирования кода, при условии что есть отдельный класс создающий кнопки он мог бы заниматься
   и отслеживанием их состояния, более того можно оптимизировать код и по координатам находить то что было нажато,
   у меня было так. Класс `Menu` в текущей реализации слишком разгружен (и создает кнопки на каждой итерации), по сути он может заниматься и обработкой событий.
4. Данный кусок кода помимо того что трижды повторяется:

```js
if speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
  speed_boll_x -= 0.5
  speed_boll_y -= 0.5
elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
  speed_boll_x += 0.5
  speed_boll_y += 0.5
elif speed_boll_x > 0 and speed_boll_y < 0: 
  speed_boll_x += 0.5
  speed_boll_y -= 0.5
elif speed_boll_x < 0 and speed_boll_y > 0: 
  speed_boll_x -= 0.5
  speed_boll_y += 0.5
```

мог бы и записан быть компактнее без потери ясности

```
speed_boll_x += 0.5 if x > 0 else -0.5
speed_boll_y += 0.5 if y > 0 else -0.5
```

Т.е. желательно избегать копипаста в коде, это приведет к его компактности и простоте обслуживания.

5. Помимо искоренения дублирования можно пользоваться средствами библиотеки, я сам давно на pygame
   ничего не писал, но заглянув в документацию увидел что этот код

   ```
    # ПРОРИСОВКА ТЕКСТ
    screen.blit(text1, (460, 10))
    screen.blit(text2, (525, 10))
    screen.blit(text3, (300, 550))
   ```

можно записать иначе:

```
    screen.blits( ((text1, (460, 10)), (text2, (525, 10)),(text3, (300, 550))) )
```

В данном случае все захардкожено но вместо того что в скобках можно передать одну переменную
и это говорит о том что больше не нужно думать где и сколько будет текста или чего-то еще,
главное - хранить это в том виде чтобы было удобно подставить в функцию отрисовки, количество не важно.

6. В процессе тестирования у меня всплыла еще одна ошибка

   ```
    # TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
    boll = pg.draw.circle(screen, WITHE, (x, y), r)
   ```

поэтому один из вариантов делать конвертацию (типы параметров функций, лучше всегда отслеживать)

```
    boll = pg.draw.circle(screen, WITHE, (int(x), int(y)), r)
```

7. Как написал @CrazyElf раз уж Вы выбрали ООП то лучше все действующие объекты сделать классами, методы которых будут по возможности компактными.
   которые будут обрабатывать свои состояния сами, путем полиморфизма они могут сами же отрисовываться,
   у меня было так.

**Желаю успешного освоения Pygame!**

*В свое время я не пожалел о затраченном времени, и осваивал его одновременно с python*

Answer (score 1):

Плюсы:

- код довольно понятно написан
- переменные хорошо названы
- есть комментарии ко всему (очень редкий случай!)

Минусы:

- мало классов/объектов: то, что у вас в основной части игры, должно быть в классе Game, а то, что у вас в классе Game, должно быть в классах Player, Bot и Ball; все вычисления должны быть в отдельных методах этих классов, в общем нужен конкретный рефакторинг, методы должны быть небольшими, каждый кусок кода с комментарием перед ним должен стать отдельным методом; на верхнем уровне код должен состоять в основном из вызова методов, по названиям которых должно быть понятно, что происходит, а уже в самих методах должны происходить мелкие детали типа добавили 0.5 к скорости, на верхнем уровне это не нужно чтобы было видно.